# My 6 year old answers teachers slowly during distance education

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler, school, speech

My 6 year old child's behaviour in zoom schooling is a bit different.
When we take his study at home, he responds well. But when it comes to responding to teachers, he answers a bit slowly.

For example, if he has to answer number name 41, in zoom schooling he will answer f---o---r---t---y---o---n---e, but with us he answers forty one.
I am not able to understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he might be a bit shy. One way to confirm this is introducing him to distant family members/neighbours. Usually it takes sometime for them to open-up. Current online scenario is difficult for kids. I recommend reading a page loudly while facing atleast 2-3 people, this will boost his confidence in the long run.

Also, another way to look at this could be: Maybe he is distracted with all different information (buttons, friends, videos of different students) available on the screen. This will improve as he is exposed more to this online environment.

No need to worry, He can do it and He will.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks !! This really helped.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a guess, but from your description and the fact that it happens during a zoom class, I'm wondering if he might be hearing echoes of himself coming back from another participant's speaker? It can be incredibly difficult to speak when you hear a delayed echo of yourself, and it will often cause these prolongations or stutterings. [There is even a device to silence speech that utilises this fact](https://phys.org/news/2012-03-speechjammer-gun-quash-human-utterances.html).

Ask the host of the meeting to make sure everybody is on mute when they're not talking. In zoom, you can be on mute and hold down space to temporarily unmute while you're talking.

If compliance with this request is low, perhaps you can instruct your child to turn the computer speakers off while responding, so he's not hearing any feedback when he's talking.

Comment: Certainly something to try.

Comment: Teacher mutes other children while one is speaking.